# Problema de Margin quando gera o PDF com MPDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

Preciso saber como tira a margin ou borda das páginas do mpdf, a primeiro momento eu queria criar um arquivo pdf que tivesse com a primeira página com este background = `background:  linear-gradient( 40deg, #4169E1 50%, white 50% );`, porém se eu coloco ele no `<body>`, o background aparece em todas as outras páginas que eu crio após, mesmo com o código de quebra páginas `<pagebreak>`,então pensei na solução de colocar dentro de uma `<div>`, porém ele não ocupa o `height` e `width` 100%(obs: mesmo eu colocando ele com height e width 100% no css), então não fica com o background que eu quero, então gostaria de saber ou como faço para tirar a borda e a margin da folha ou como faço para que quando eu quebre uma página ela não puxe o css do `body` antigo.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Mpdf\Mpdf;
$mpdf = new Mpdf();

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<body style="border:0px; height:100% width:100%;">
<div style="background-color: solid;
height:100%;
border:0px;
width:100%;
background:  linear-gradient( 40deg, #4169E1 50%, white 50% );
margin:0px;
padding:0px;">
<section >

<p style="font-size:32pt; padding-bottom:0pt; padding-top: 110pt;padding-left: 170pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: Left;">Proposta Comercial</p>

<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\wp-bootstrap-starter\imgs\Logo_Grupo-Avante.png" alt="some text" style="padding:0px; margin-top:450px;" width=511 >

</section></div></body><pagebreak>');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="background-color: solid; background: white; height:100%;
width:100%; ">'. $page_1 .'</div>');
```

Queria no caso colocar apenas a primeira página com esse style

```
style="background-color: solid;
    height:100%;
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    background:  linear-gradient( 40deg, #4169E1 50%, white 50% );
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;"
```

[O `style` dentro da `div` fica assim:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm20E.jpg)

[O `style` dentro do `body` fica assim:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68QGv.jpg)